# Requesting whole features implementations as answers to questions

Tags: discussion, questions

What is the "official" policy regarding users who consistently request whole features implementations as answers to their questions? In spite of down voting, the OP could be persistent in editing his question and/or re-posting it in order to re-surface and get someone answer him out of pity. This way, he gets his job done "for free", and I question whether it would be appropriate for SO to allow for such behavior. Is it ok to bring such cases to moderator's attention by flagging? I'm linking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716047/need-help-in-implementing-team-overall-rating-system) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691421/how-would-i-implement-a-team-payroll-with-built-in-salary-cap) question as specific examples.

Comment: voted to close both questions due to vagueness and lack of OP effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell there is no official policy governing this situation.  And this is good, because if the creation of an official policy is required for every permutation of bad question, the hosts would spend all day writing policies!

We rely on the tools of down-voting, editing and commenting to allow the community to correct the situation.

As to what **you** can do ...
- Vote the question down if it bothers you.
- If you have sufficient rep .. vote to close it.
- Flag it for moderator attention if you think it crosses an appropriateness line.
- Write a comment suggesting ways that the OP could improve the question.
- Ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the question is valid. I would either down vote it or leave it be.  There will be enough people with a rep high enough to close it if the question is deemed vague, too localized, etc.

Comment: And what if you're one of those people with high enough rep? What then?

Comment: @Ether I would say that depends on your judgment on whether or not to close the question. I go back and forth as to what to do in these situations, but I know a lot of people will vote to close, so normally I don't vote to do so.